# Send alpha value to fragment shader

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a fragment shader :

```
precision mediump float;

uniform vec4 vColor;
uniform sampler2D u_Texture;    // The input texture.

varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;   // Interpolated texture coordinate per fragment.
varying vec4 vAlpha;
void main() {
 gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate).xyz, texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate).w * vAlpha[3]);

}
```

And vertex shader :

```
attribute vec3 vPosition;
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord; // Per-vertex texture coordinate information we will pass in.
attribute vec4 aAlpha;
varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;
varying vec4 vAlpha;
void main() {
     v_TexCoordinate = aTextureCoord;
     vAlpha = aAlpha;
     gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vec4(vPosition,1.0);
}
```

And try to set alpha value to texture from my program.

```
private final int mAlphaHandle;
private float[] color = {0.5f};
```

Set :

```
mAlphaHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram,"aAlpha");
```

Using :

```
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mAlphaHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mAlphaHandle, 1,GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,4, alphaBuffer);
```

Blending is enabled.

```
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
    GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

But i have no effect on the screen. So a question is why i getting no effect on the screen? Actually a want to change alpha value dynamically in the future.

Comment: If you replace "vAlpha[3]" with 1.0 can you see the scene (if not the problem is not in your alpha buffer)? Also what is your alphaBuffer?

Comment: I sure hope your GLSL compiler is smart enough not to actually do two texture fetches :) I would consider `gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate) * vec4 (vec3 (1.0), vAlpha[3]);` instead just in case.